# How do I unit test a controller that is decorated with the ServiceFilterAttribute, custom ActionFilter implementation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, .net-core, custom-action-filter

*Summary*:

- I'm trying to test a **controller** with an **ActionFilter** implementation
- Unit test fails, because ActionFilter does not get invoked in unit test.
- Testing via Postman works as expected and the correct result is achieved.
- Can the controller be tested like this or should it move to integration test?

*Breakdown*:

I'm able to test the ActionFilter on its own in a unit test, what I would like to do is test the controller in a unit test.

The action filter looks like this:

```
 public class ValidateEntityExistAttribute<T> : IActionFilter
        where T : class, IEntityBase
    {
        readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;
        public ValidateEntityExistAttribute(AppDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            this._appDbContext = appDbContext;
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {}

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ActionArguments.ContainsKey("id"))
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult("The id must be passed as parameter");
                return;
            }

            int id = (int)context.ActionArguments["id"];

            var foundEntity = _appDbContext.Set<T>().Find(id);
            if (foundEntity == null)
                context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
            else
                context.HttpContext.Items.Add("entity_found", foundEntity);
        }
    }
```

The ActionFilter implementation is added to the services in the startup file

```
ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
 services.AddScoped<ValidateEntityExistAttribute<Meeting>>();
...
}
```

The filter can be applied to any controller method that needs to check if an entity exists. ie the GetById method.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidateEntityExistAttribute<Meeting>))]
public async Task<ActionResult<MeetingDto>> GetById(int id)
    {            
        var entity = HttpContext.Items["entity_found"] as Meeting;
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        return Ok(entity.ConvertTo<MeetingDto>());
    }
```

In the xUnit test I have set up the test to test the controller like this:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Get_Meeting_Record_By_Id()
{
    // Arrange
    var _AppDbContext = AppDbContextMocker.GetAppDbContext(nameof(Get_All_Meeting_Records));
    var _controller = InitializeController(_AppDbContext);

    //Act
    
    var all = await _controller.GetById(1);

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(1, all.Value.Id);

    //clean up otherwise the other test will complain about key tracking.
    await _AppDbContext.DisposeAsync();
}
```

and this is what the InitializeController method look like, I left the commented lines so that it is visible to what I have tried, none of the commented code worked.
I mocked and used the default classes.

```
private MeetingController InitializeController(AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {

        var _controller = new MeetingController(appDbContext);

        var spf = new DefaultServiceProviderFactory(new ServiceProviderOptions { ValidateOnBuild = true, ValidateScopes = true });
        var sc = spf.CreateBuilder(new ServiceCollection());

        sc.AddMvc();
        sc.AddControllers();
        //(config =>
        //{
        //    config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateAttribute());
        //    config.Filters.Add(new ValidateEntityExistAttribute<Meeting>(appDbContext));
        //});
        
        sc.AddTransient<ValidateModelStateAttribute>();
        sc.AddTransient<ValidateEntityExistAttribute<Meeting>>();

        var sp = sc.BuildServiceProvider();

        //var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            RequestServices = sp
        };
        //mockHttpContext.Setup(cx => cx.RequestServices).Returns(sp);

        //var contDesc = new ControllerActionDescriptor();
        //var context = new ControllerContext();
        //var context = new ControllerContext(new ActionContext(mockHttpContext.Object, new RouteData(), contDesc));

        //context.HttpContext = mockHttpContext.Object;
        //context.HttpContext = httpContext;
        //_controller.ControllerContext = context;
        _controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = httpContext;

        return _controller;
    }
```

**The issues** I have is that when running the unit test the ActionFilter implementation is never invoked, thus breaking the test because  `var entity = HttpContext.Items["entity_found"] as Meeting;` in the controller is always **null**! more accurately `HttpContext.Items` is always null.

The break point in the ActionFilter never gets hit.

*When this is tested via postman it all works as expected, and the break point gets hit*

Is there a way to test the controller as a unit test this way, *or should this test now just move to integration*?

Comment: Please note that a [controller unit test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#unit-testing-controllers) avoids scenarios such as filters, routing, and model binding. For unit test, you do not need to test the filter on a particular controller action, you can test the filter itself.

Comment: Thank you @Fei Han! That does clear up why the filters aren't triggered. I guess, with a controller with this little implementation, there is almost no value in writing a unit test for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Fei Han for the link [about unit testing controllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#unit-testing-controllers).

As it turns out this is by design, as stated in the microsoft documentation

> **Unit testing controllers**
> *Set up unit tests of controller actions to*
> *focus on the controller's behavior. A controller unit test avoids*
> *scenarios such as filters, routing, and model binding. Tests that*
> *cover the interactions among components that collectively respond to a*
> *request are handled by integration tests.*

So the test should move to integration testing.

In *this particular scenario*, where there is no detailed implementation for the `GetById(int id)` method, there is almost no value in doing a *unit test* for it.

If the `GetById(int id)` method had a more complex implementation, or if the *ActionFilter* did not prevent further processing, the `HttpContext.Items["entity_found"]` should be mocked.